# WCF when do I need to use pipe binding?

Tags: wcf, named-pipes

When do I need to use pipe binding?
Is it possible to have a WCF service and a ASP.NET client which have a pipe binding endpoint?

Or do I only need to use pipe binding if I want to talk against another WCF service on the same computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NetNamdPipeBinding is used for interprocess communication. You may prefer to develop your IPC mechanism using WCF rather than learning and dealing with an older technology like .NET Remoting. Also, even if the two services run on the same machine, if at some point you decide you want them to run on separate machines, all you need to do is switch the binding.

Answer (score 0):

NamedPipes can only be used when the client and host are on the same physical machine. It is the fastest way to communicate using WCF while ensuring de-coupling.

Comment: But why do you need to ever use a service if you have the same application on your own machine ?

Comment: One reason would be if you were calling a potentially long running service, you could call it asynchronously or on-way. This would allow you to free up process threads in the calling client.